# Automate Firebase Tools CLI operations

Tags: firebase, automation, command-line-interface

I am trying to automate using the Firebase-tools CLI. For example, automatically using firebase login and copying the URL it provides to authorise an account.

So the code needs to run 'firebase login:ci --interactive', wait for the URL to be displayed, grab the URL and use it in puppeteer.

Also the code will automatically create projects using 'firebase init hosting', so it'll need to go through the menus (pressing y, scrolling to create project, typing in the wanted project name)

And also deploying.

Is this even possible to do?